# activate a function if i hover over an article in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, hover

this is my html code:

```html
<div class="TestClass">
    <main>
        <article id="WortArticle">
            <h2>Wort</h2>
            <p>Testparagraph </p>
        </article>

        <article id="WortArticle2">
            <h2>Wort2</h2>
            <p>Testparagraph2 </p>
        </article>
```

and so on...

ive got a function that changes the content of each h2 and each p element but i only want it to be activated if i hover over my articles in my site.
How can i do that?

Ive tried:

```js
let onArticleHover = document.querySelectorAll(".TestClass");
onArticleHover.addEventListener("mouseover", myfunction());
```

it works but not if i hover but from the start. i need it to only activate when i hover over an article.

thank you so much

Comment: the html code is inbetween the <div class="TestClass" </div>
i forgot that

Comment: Change `.addEventListener("mouseover", myfunction());` to `.addEventListener("mouseover", myfunction);`. Don't forget about dynamic `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try having another function to reverse the effect of the first function.

```
onArticleHover.addEventListener("mouseout", anotherFunctionName);
```

Another function should reverse back the changes.

Answer (score -1):

Close the div and main. You can use `onmouseover="a()" onmouseout="b()"` in the HTML tag. Function a can change text and Function b can change it back to its original state.

[onmouseover event - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp)